# Is it OK to up-vote a team member's Stack Overflow question?

Tags: discussion

I'm working as a developer in a small software company. We use Stack Overflow all the time to get help and help others.

If my team (2-3 developers) post a question on Stack Overflow, we are encouraged to up-vote the question in order for it to gain traction and answers (and **not** for getting more reputation).

**Is this behavior considered voting fraud?**

You could argue that all team members are experiencing the same problem, and therefore up-voting the question is acceptable.

You could also argue that the up-votes does not represent the "real-world" relevance of the question, and thereby distorting the very voting system we all love.

I don't know who started to encourage this behaviour, and now it seems that everybody does it because it has proven effective.

Comment: _"experiencing the same problem"_ - that doesn't make it a good question. _"encouraged to up-vote the question"_ - encouraged by whom?

Comment: @gnat if the motive is to get more reputation, its obviously voting fraud. Our motive is to make the question gain traction (nothing to do with reputation). Only members on the team experiencing the problem would up-vote

Comment: ".. all team members are experiencing the same problem .." so essentially it's just one question (albeit from a set of people). So you could also argue that they should *not* upvote it individually.

Comment: The rule is kind of simple: "Vote for the content, not the author", If you're voting for a teammate question because it's a teammate and maybe your question also your not evaluating the content, it's a fraud whatever the reason driving it. Side note: We can't vote for our own posts.

Comment: The safest way is to just  not do it.