# Usage of Stack Overflow in medium sized close teams/circles

Tags: discussion

As a software outsourcing company, we have an internal system that link our current software development Q&A to Stack Overflow posts. Developers are encouraged to make research on the internal system first and upvote what they found helpful.

Naturally, these questions/answers have a much higher upvote per view/per quality rate, etc...

Lets say we have some 2000 developer in such circle.

Edit: I read previous question on the topic of [voting rings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338737/is-it-ok-to-up-vote-a-team-members-stack-overflow-question) and related [stuff](https://web.archive.org/web/20150201115645/http://alertfalse.com/2013/10/lessons-from-hofstede-part-1-power-distance/) and would like to provide more context to the current situation.

- These are all experienced IT workers and have an idea how Stack Overflow works
- The questions and and answers are legit and follow the site's rules.
- Voting is actually based on content and follows the [site's rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) also. People just favor what they found "first" by the internal system.
- One could argue that they just have better sharing where the questions (and answer) that interest them the most are "highlighted" over the other ones
- I have not seen this talk on medium sized group of couple thousand people who are not just blindly voting for each other.

Is this encouraged/discouraged?

Answer (score 6):

That depends. If you're sending your users to your own (or each other's own) posts, then what you're describing is a large-scale voter ring. That's strongly discouraged.

If, on the other hand, you're just sending your people to posts that are relevant to their work, then that's really no different than if they found those posts via Google. Nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I edited the post to reflect that this is not a duplicate. 
In this case, employees are encouraged to upvote anything that helps. The answer could be from any one not in the ring ( top voted - accepted answer often help ) . The questions are often created by some one inside the ring  and will be upvoted if the other one share the same question.